# Rust error "PermissionDenied: Operation Not Permitted" when creating pnet datalink channel

Tags: networking, rust

The example datalink channel creation code used in the "Ethernet echo server" example on [pnet's main doc page](https://docs.rs/pnet/0.27.2/pnet/index.html) includes this snippet:

```
// Create a new channel, dealing with layer 2 packets
    let (mut tx, mut rx) = match datalink::channel(&interface, Default::default()) {
        Ok(Ethernet(tx, rx)) => (tx, rx),
        Ok(_) => panic!("Unhandled channel type"),
        Err(e) => panic!("An error occurred when creating the datalink channel: {}", e)
    };
```

This doesn't work on my CentOS7, throwing the error: `thread 'main' panicked at 'An error occurred when creating the datalink channel: Os { code: 1, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Operation not permitted" }', src/bin/main.rs:83:27`

Recreate with the above, or more simply:

```
use pnet::datalink;
fn main() {
    for i in datalink::interfaces() {
        println!("{}", i.name);
        match datalink::channel(&i, Default::default()) {
            Ok(_) => println!("OK"),
            Err(_) => println!("ERR")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems much more likely to me that the closure is not to blame but that the OS returns Permission denied for a particular interface you are trying to open.

Comment: @HHK except the code runs fine when not in a closure, as mentioned.

Comment: Or at least I *thought* it did before, but I tried it again out of impulse and sure enough the closure doesn't matter!  I feel terrible.  I still can't figure out what could need permission though.

Comment: pnet is trying to open a [raw socket](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html). That usually requires root permissions.

Comment: Heavily edited the question to fit the current state of issues.

Comment: @HHK What's the best way to run the cargo payload with root permissions... `sudo cargo run` ?

Comment: Figured it out: `cargo run` then `sudo target/debug/main` and it worked this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pnet is trying to open a [raw socket](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html) which requires root permissions or the CAP_NET_RAW capability. That causes the *Operation not permitted* error. Running as root resolves the issue.